# Pick shiftwidth from file

Tags: indentation, vi, vim

I have kept shiftwidth as 4 in my vimrc file. But, when I open many existing c/h files, they have shiftwidth as 2. So, these gets mixed up.

Can I automatically select the shiftwidth from the file than setting it each time I open the files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a modeline at the bottom of the file:

```
/* vim: set sw=2: */
```

[More on modelines.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic)

Comment: Beaten to it :-) @Manoj for completeness, do a `:help modeline` to read more about this

Answer (score 4):

Modelines are not the best way to go about solving this, in my opinion. Modelines were (are?) vulnerable to a security issue. (see http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/vim-modelines-insecure and http://secunia.com/advisories/25182/ for more information)

Instead, you can disable modelines and use a plugin to scan the files you open and automatically set `shiftwidth`, `tabstop` and others depending on the code that is there already. I use [YAIFA](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096) to do this, but there are others on vim.org.

Comment: Thank you. I am selecting this as the most expected answer. There are 100s of existing files, and it is difficult for me to go and add the modeline on all of them. (also, they will fire me if I change the files unnecessarily...:)  ) This will save from it, and will only remain in my work space/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify the settings from within the file itself by using a *modeline*, e.g.

```
/* vim: set ts=2 sw=2: */
```

For further details, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic